# Obtaining a list of events registered on a component in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to determine which events are being listened to in a component. In the following example, `customEvent1` and `customEvent2` are being passed event handlers, and `customEvent3` is not being used. Is there a way I can get this list, specifically in AfterViewInit?

```
<my-component (customEvent1)="onCustomEvent1($event)" (customEvent2)="onCustomEvent2($event)"></my-component>
```

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Output() customEvent1: EventEmitter<object> = new EventEmitter<object>();
  @Output() customEvent2: EventEmitter<object> = new EventEmitter<object>();
  @Output() customEvent3: EventEmitter<object> = new EventEmitter<object>();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Obtain a list of what events that were registered (['customEvent1', 'customEvent2'])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by accessing the `observers` properties, since EventEmitter extends the RxJs Subject:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(!!this.customEvent1.observers.length); // Will output false if not used
}
```

Comment: Note that I did tested it locally, 
although it works, it will throw "Expression has changed after it was checked." (I did used the boolean output to feed a property on component). Probably ngAfterViewInit is not the best hook to use.